# jQuery selecting div to change background on radio button click

Tags: jquery, image, show

I have a set of dynamic radio buttons that all show/hide certain fields when selected, and I'm trying to have the same jQuery block that shows and hide fields also show the correct preview image.  It's for a wordpress theme.  The container (tested with CSS setting background to an image) is called #layoutpreview.  Here is the jQuery I'm using to switch the background-image:

```
if (layoutchecked =="tc") 
{
   jQuery('#CWP_layout').nextAll('div').hide('')
    var layoutchecked = jQuery('.radio_wrapper').children('input:checked').attr('value') 
    if (layoutchecked =="tc") 
                {
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk1txt').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk1txt').addClass('setShowing');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk1bgcolor').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk1icon').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk2txt').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk2bgcolor').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk2icon').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk3txt').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk3bgcolor').show('');
                jQuery('#CWP_tcblk3icon').show('');
                jQuery('#layoutpreview').css("background-image", "url('images/previews/3-column-layout.jpg')");
                alert ("we changed it");
                }
}
```

The HTML is being written as the WordPress theme takes in an array, and spits out radio buttons, here is the generated HTML code:

```
<div id="CWP_layout" class="cwp_input cwp_radio"> 

    <label for="CWP_layout">Select Layout</label> 

     <div class="radio_wrapper"> 


       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="tc" checked='checked' class="CWP_layout"/>Three Columns<br />  
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="tr"  class="CWP_layout"/>Three Rows<br /> 
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="is"  class="CWP_layout"/>Image Slider<br /> 
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="iwc"  class="CWP_layout"/>Image with Content<br />             
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="osi"  class="CWP_layout"/>One Single Image<br /> 
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="fsev"  class="CWP_layout"/>Full Size Embedded Video<br /> 
       <input type="radio" name="CWP_layout" value="vwti"  class="CWP_layout"/>Video with Three Images<br /> 
        </div> 
        <small>Select the layout for the theme.</small><div class="clearfix"></div> 
     <div id="layoutpreviewwrap">Layout Of Selected Theme<div id="layoutpreview"></div><br />       
     </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: There's no enough info here to know what isn't working.  You will have to show a lot more of your code.

Comment: The same script works for me.
Are you missing a '/' infront of image url? Check your image location.

Comment: Added more code.  The image, from where the jQuery is located (and tested in css) is in Images --> Previews --> Filename.jpg.  When I use the same path in the CSS, it works like a charm for the image that I set static.

Comment: tested with background-color "red" and that works just fine

Comment: Hmm. Have you checked for case-sensitivity? In your code you use `images/previews/3-column-layout.jpg` but in you comment you state `Images --> Previews --> Filename.jpg`, i.e. capitalized folder names...

Comment: Yeah that was just a general statement.  it's so weird, when I change the jQuery to .css('background-color', 'red') it changes it... but NO images will input into that field...

Comment: you can't change the background-image unless it has been preloaded and cached by the browser. try load()

Comment: Solved my own problem.  Just added a class, .tcbg, and set the background image there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
jQuery('#layoutpreview').css("background-image", "url('images/previews/3-column-layout.jpg')");
```

to this

```
jQuery('#layoutpreview').css("background-image", "url('../images/previews/3-column-layout.jpg')");
```

Note the `../`

You may need to add more than one of these if the file with the scripting is several "layers" away from the images folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: Didn't work either, but I think the class option I posted above will work for me.  How do you strip classes off a div, just with removeClass() and leave it empty?

Comment: Yes, just use `removeClass()`.